# Math formulas not working in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I often experience problems with evaluating expressions like `sqrt(\x)` or `2^{\x^2}` in TikZ pictures.  Here is an example:

```
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[draw=gray!50!white,fill=gray!50!white] 
    plot[smooth,samples=100,domain=0:1] (\x*\x,1+\x) -- 
    plot[smooth,samples=100,domain=0:1] (\x,2^{\x^2});
\draw[domain=0:1] plot (\x*\x,1+\x);
\draw[samples=100,domain=0:1] plot (\x,2^{\x^2});
\draw (-.5,0)--(1.25,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw (0,-.5)--(0,2.25) node[above]{$y$};
\draw (1,2pt)--(1,-2pt) node[below] {$1$};
\foreach \y/\ytext in {1,2}
\draw (2pt,\y)--(-2pt,\y) node[left] {$\y$};    
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

I managed to avoid using `sqrt(\x)`, but I can't get the other function to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need some corrections. For tiKZ to parse the function expression correctly, it needs two culy braces around it. So, `(\x*\x,1+\x)` should be `({\x*\x},{1+\x})` and so on for the rest of the expressions. Also, why avoid `sqrt(\x)` or the like? TikZ can easily deal with these functions as for example `\pgfmathsqrt{x} \pgfmathresult`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[draw=gray!50!white,fill=gray!50!white] 
    plot[smooth,samples=100,domain=0:1] ({\x*\x},{1+\x}) -- 
    plot[smooth,samples=100,domain=0:1] ({\x},{2^(\x^2)});
\draw[domain=0:1] plot (\x*\x,1+\x);
\draw[samples=100,domain=0:1] plot ({\x},{2^(\x^2)});
\draw (-.5,0)--(1.25,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw (0,-.5)--(0,2.25) node[above]{$y$};
\draw (1,2pt)--(1,-2pt) node[below] {$1$};
\foreach \y/\ytext in {1,2}
\draw (2pt,\y)--(-2pt,\y) node[left] {$\y$};    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great!  It solved my problem.  I tried the braces, but I must have put them in the wrong place.  Thank you!

Comment: @PiotrMikusinski They are needed only when there are parentheses are involved in the formula to hide them from the parser.